# Schedule clickhouse table optimization, ReplacingMergeTree

Tags: clickhouse

We are using Clickhouse's [`ReplacingMergeTree`](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree).
We would like to ensure that our table has no duplicates in it, for data older than about an hour or so.

Clickhouse's documentation makes it pretty clear that partition merges happen in the background at an unknown time.

> Data deduplication occurs only during a merge. Merging occurs in the background at an unknown time, so you can’t plan for it. Some of the data may remain unprocessed. Although you can run an unscheduled merge using the `OPTIMIZE` query, do not count on using it, because the `OPTIMIZE` query will read and write a large amount of data.
>
> Thus, `ReplacingMergeTree` is suitable for clearing out duplicate data in the background in order to save space, but it does not guarantee the absence of duplicates.

We can tolerate duplicates for newly inserted data, however we would like older data to be reliably de-duplicated.

Does Clickhouse have a built-in mechanism to schedule table optimization at a given frequency(eg every hour)?

Or would we need to setup some kind of external cron job to request table optimization?

Answer (score 2):

See https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/merge-tree-settings#min_age_to_force_merge_seconds

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/merge-tree-settings#min_age_to_force_merge_on_partition_only

But you should be careful, performance impact depends on partitioning.

Comment: After testing, configuring a `min_age_to_force_merge_seconds`, clickhouse now merges smaller parts, however my table still contains duplicates older than an hour, it seems like like it still won't merge with the largest part unless I optimize final manually, setting `min_age_to_force_merge_on_partition_only` to true doesn't appear to help.

Comment: report it to github with evidences